# strange wrong char's encryption (ascii)

Tags: c++, encryption, ascii

It's a simple code but I can't understand a strange event.
Code:

```
void Crittografia::CifraTesto(char text[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(text);i++){
        text[i]=text[i] + key;
        if(text[i] > 'z'){
            text[i]=text[i] - 26;
        }
    }
}
```

The function receives the string entered here: 
[It works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwWXP.png).
In this case it works with a key of 5. 'y' changed in 'd' correctly.

But in this case: [Doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc9EK.png).
With a key of 7 it changes 'y' in 'Ç' instead of the correct 'f', so apparently doesn't execute the row: "text[i]=text[i] - 26;"

Comment: You need to learn how to copy text from a console window.  On Windows operating systems, right click on the title bar, choose  Edit->Mark.  With the mouse, highlight the region to copy, then press Enter.  This will place the highlighted text onto the clipboard so it can be pasted into your question.

Comment: An [ASCII table reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) might be a good start. Then you might know why e.g. `someCharacteer - 26` might not be such a good idea.

Comment: There is no `::` in C so your question is not `C` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Giorgi said, your problem is with overflow.  You can avoid it by subtracting `key` from both sides of the inequality:

```
for (int i=0; text[i]; i++) {
    if (text[i] > 'z' - key) // check whether (text[i] + key) would be past `z`
        text[i] -= 26 - key;
    else
        text[i] += key;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> text[i]=text[i] + key;

When key is 7 and `text[i]` is `'y'` addition result doesn't fit in `char` (seems your char is signed) and result is implementation defined.

You are better of using a modulo operator in the addition. e.g.

```
text[i]= (text[i] - 'a' + key) % 26 + 'a';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the *modulus* operator, '%'.
Search StackOverflow for "c++ caesar cipher" for more examples of this assignment.

Example:

```
new_letter = (old_letter - 'a'); // Set the range from 0 to 25.
new_letter = (new_letter + key) % 26; // 26 letters in the alphabet.
new_letter += 'a'; // Convert back to a letter.
```

Comment: Modulus is useful, but not necessary.  In addition one can compute modulus without ever using `%`.

Comment: @BenVoigt But we all use modulus and OP will be seeing it in everyone else's code.